# Cannot publish via clickonce after windows reinstallation due to key problems

Tags: .net, clickonce, manifest, code-signing

After I reinstalled windows my `clickonce` `signing` does not work anymore. Clicking `publish` gives me a pop up saying:

```
"The application is signed with a different key than the existing application on the server. Do you want to overwrite it?"
```

According to the MS Help clicking yes will cause my users to stop getting automatic updates. I also got a warning about the culture settings but after setting en this is checked and cannot be the problem. I found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955332/what-is-signing-clickonce-manifests-for) but without a helping answer to solve it. Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
It was a problem with the certificates expiring date.

**Solution:**
I downloaded the `renewCert Tool` from [here](http://may.be/renewcert/). Be carefully, you have to use the [project as a zip file](http://may.be/renewcert/RenewCert.zip) link and compile it yourself. For this to run you have to add `Crypt32.dll` to `Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` for `Configuration: Release`.

Now I used the command line to extend my certificates expiring date. Now it works.